# Getting error while trying to work with spring-jms and IBM MQ

Tags: spring, jms, ibm-mq

```
Could not create JMS transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory does not implement the requested int
erface javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
        at org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager.doBegin(JmsTransactionManager.java:255)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:137)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run(TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory does not implement the requested interface javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
        at org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.doCreateConnection(UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.java:188)
        at org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.createConnection(UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.java:162)
        at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.doCreateConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:409)
        at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.initConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:349)
        at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.getConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:327)
        at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.createConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:242)
        at org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager.createConnection(JmsTransactionManager.java:330)
        at org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager.doBegin(JmsTransactionManager.java:223)
        ... 9 more
```

Comment: You appear to use transaction. I think you need to use MQXAConnectionFactory.

Comment: Please provide more than the error message you received.   Pedicure the configuration that resulted in that error.